# Typeahead reading data from the Object - not work

Tags: angular, typeahead, ng-bootstrap

for example data:

```
 [{
    "_id":"5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7",
    "username":"cccc",
    "password":"$2a$05$.5lmx/",
    "description":"testowy opis",
    "email":"cccc@gmail.com",
    "type":"2","__v":0,
        "address":{"street":"Bleecker","houseNumber":"54","city":"New York"}
},{
    "_id":"5ab655bbb94733156c438112",
    "username":"rrrr",
    "password":"$2a$05$/",
    "description":"ddd",
    "email":"rrrr",
    "type":"3",
    "__v":0,
        "address":{"street":"Wall Street","houseNumber":"3","city":"New York"}
}]
```

geting from the method :

```
getExample() {

    this.exampleService.getExample().subscribe(res => {

      this.test =  res.data ;
      console.log(' this.test ' + JSON.stringify(this.test));  // result data          
    });
}
```

How to filter the downloaded data `this.test`?

```
@ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
focus$ = new Subject<string>();
click$ = new Subject<string>();

search = (text$:  Observable<string>) => 
    text$
      .debounceTime(200).distinctUntilChanged()
      .merge(this.focus$)
      .merge(this.click$.filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()))
      .map(term => (term === '' ? this.test : this.test.filter(v =>
         v.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)
    ).slice(0, 10)
  )
```

after entering the mark in `input`:

```
<input  id="typeahead-focus"  type="text"  class="form-control" 
[(ngModel)]="user"  [ngbTypeahead]="search" 
(focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)" 
(click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" #instance="ngbTypeahead" />
```

How to display `username` in the drop down list?

[object Object] is displayed. 
How to correct the dropdown list to download `username`?

Comment: What typeahead component are you using ?

Comment: `v` seems to be one entry from your data, so an object with `id`, `username`, etc. You cannot use `toLowerCase` on an object.

Comment: [typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) Open on focus. The example is on `string[]` and I need it on`Object`. I do not know how to convert it to get the `username` parameter from the object. The sample data is in the post.

Comment: `v` is an element of your test arra. It's an object. Objects don't have a toLowerCase() function. One what part of the object do you want to filter? The ID? The username? the street of the address?

Comment: How to download the `username` from the Obiect (The sample data is in the post)?

Comment: JB Nizet  - `username`

Comment: Then the code should be `this.test.filter(v =>
      v.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)`.

Comment: JB Nizet Iit's almost working. After entering the character. it filters, but in the drop down list it shows: [object Object]

Comment: Look at the example "Template for result" in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

Comment: JB Nizet  I edited the post, the data displays [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

**solution**

`<input  id="typeahead-focus"  type="text"   class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user"  [ngbTypeahead]="search" (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)" (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" #instance="ngbTypeahead"
 [resultFormatter]="format" [inputFormatter]="format" />`

```
@ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
focus$ = new Subject<string>();
click$ = new Subject<string>();
format = (value: any) => value.username || '';
    search = (text$:  Observable<string>) => //  Observable<string>
    text$
      .debounceTime(200).distinctUntilChanged()
      .merge(this.focus$)
      .merge(this.click$.filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()))
      .map(term => (term === 'Brak' ? this.test : this.test.filter(v =>
        v.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
```